# parsec: parse nested code blocks

Tags: haskell, parsec, parser-combinators

I want to parse following text:

```
keyword some more values
        funcKeyw funcName1
        funcKeyw funcName2

        funcKeyw funcName3

        keyword some more values
                 funcKeyw funcName2

        keyword some more values
                 funcKeyw funcName4
```

Indentation is done by tabs. Each block is started by `keyword` and some additional values in the same line. Everything indented belongs to the same block. **After** all the function calls (that start with the `funcKeyw`  keyword) there can be child `keyword` blocks (separated by an "empty" line; "empty" means either nothing in it or whitespace characters).

```
type IndentLevel = Int

data Block = Block { blockFuncCalls :: [String]
                   , blockBlocks    :: [Block]
                   }

block :: GenParser Char st Block
block = parseBlock 0
    where
        parseBlock lvl = do
            count lvl tab
            string "keyword"
            -- [...] Parse other stuff in that line.
            newline

            -- Parse 'function calls'.
            fs <- sepBy1 (blockFunc (lvl + 1)) emptyLines
            -- Parse optional child blocks.
            emptyLines
            bs <- sepBy (parseBlock (lvl + 1)) emptyLines

            return Block { blockFuncCalls=fs
                         , blockBlocks=bs
                         }

blockFunc :: IndentLevel -> GenParser Char st String
blockFunc lvl = do
    count lvl tab
    string "funcKeyw"
    -- [...] Parse function name etc..
    newline
    return funcName -- Parsed func name.

emptyLine :: GenParser Char st ()
emptyLine = many (oneOf "\t ") >> newline >> return ()

emptyLines :: GenParser Char st ()
emptyLines = many emptyLine >> return ()
```

The problem is that the `blockFunc` parser does not stop parsing when the child block starts, but returns an error `unexpected 'keyword'`.

How can I avoid that? I think I could use `try` or `choice` to choose the correct parser for each line, but I want to require the function calls to be before the child blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I have noticed is that the `sepBy` combinators have somewhat unexpected behaviour, namely, that if the separator is began to be parsed, and that fails, the entire `sepBy` fails, instead of simple returning what was parsed so far. You can use the following variants, which differ by an additional `try` inside of `sepBy1Try`:

```
sepBy1Try :: (Stream s m t) => ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m sep -> ParsecT s u m [a]
sepBy1Try p sep = do
  x <- p
  xs <- many (try $ sep *> p)
  return (x:xs)

sepByTry p sep = sepBy1Try p sep <|> return []
```

Use these in place of `sepBy`:

```
block :: GenParser Char st Block
block = parseBlock 0
    where
        parseBlock lvl = do
            count lvl tab
            string "keyword"

            otherStuff <- many (noneOf "\r\n") 
            newline

            -- Parse 'function calls'.
            fs <- sepBy1Try (blockFunc (lvl + 1)) emptyLines

            -- Parse optional child blocks.
            emptyLines
            bs <- sepByTry (try $ parseBlock (lvl + 1)) emptyLines

            return Block { blockFuncCalls=fs
                         , blockBlocks=bs
                         , blockValues=words otherStuff
                         }
```

I also modified your datatype to also capture some more information (just for demonstration purposes). Also, note yet another `try` in front of the recursive `parseBlock` - this is because this parses must fail without consuming input, when it sees for example one tab, but is expecting two, this `try` allows it to backtrack to the "next level".

Finally, change the following:

```
emptyLines :: GenParser Char st ()
emptyLines = many (try emptyLine) >> return ()
```

Same reasoning as sepBy here...

---

A test with a simple pretty printer for clarity:

```
data Block = Block { blockValues :: [String]
                   , blockFuncCalls :: [String]
                   , blockBlocks    :: [Block]
                   } deriving (Show, Eq) 

pprBlock :: Block -> String 
pprBlock = unlines . go id where 
  go ii (Block vals funcs subblocks) = 
    let ii' = ii . ('\t':) in 
    (ii $ unwords $ "keyword":vals) : 
    map (\f -> ii' $ "function " ++ f) funcs ++ 
    concatMap (go ii') subblocks

test0_run = either (error.show) (putStrLn.pprBlock) $ parse block "" $ test0

test0 = unlines $ 
  [ "keyword some more values"
  , "\tfuncKeyw funcName1"
  , "\tfuncKeyw funcName2"
  , "\t"
  , "\tfuncKeyw funcName3"
  , "\t"
  , "\tkeyword some more values"
  , "\t\tfuncKeyw funcName2"
  , ""
  , "\tkeyword some more values"
  , "\t\tfuncKeyw funcName4"
  ]
```

and

```
>test0_run
keyword some more values
        function funcName1
        function funcName2
        function funcName3
        keyword some more values
                function funcName2
        keyword some more values
                function funcName4

>putStrLn test0
keyword some more values
        funcKeyw funcName1
        funcKeyw funcName2

        funcKeyw funcName3

        keyword some more values
                funcKeyw funcName2

        keyword some more values
                funcKeyw funcName4

>
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much! I replaced the implementation of `sepBy1Try` with `liftM2 (:) p (many (try $ sep *> p))` to make the `do` go away.